# GDPR - updating preferences / forgetme

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, gdpr

Wordpress 4.9.5 / CiviCRM 4.7.31 / GDPR extension 2.1

How do I pass tokens to the GDPR communications preference page (using Veda's extension)?

I've got the Communications Preference link working (not quite as formatted in the extension control panel, I think it's a Drupal / WP thing);

https://yoursite.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/gdpr/comms-prefs/update

Which works great (when I'm logged in). However, when I visit as an anonymous user, I get a blank page. I could ask all my contacts to re-type their details in, however, the scope for errors / duplication / drop-out makes this less than ideal.

I can format an email to send a token to update a profile but that doesn't pick up the GDPR consent date / data:

https://yoursite.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=profileID&id=userID&cs=checkSum

When I try and pass those tokens I get a blank form, so it's not picking up the userID and loading the relevant data from the db:

https://yoursite.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/gdpr/comms-prefs/update&id=userID&cs=checkSum

I'm pretty sure this is possible (the built in tokens should provide this function), however, the built in tokens don't seem to generate valid links or URLs (or indeed anything).

{contact.comm_pref_supporter_link}

{contact.comm_pref_supporter_url}

I can include {contact.checksum} and preview email as html and see a checksum, but the comm_pref tokens stay as {contact....}

If someone can post a valid tokenised Communications Preference page I can probably reverse engineer something.

So again, not sure if Drupal / WP related or some other missing dependancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've addressed this issue in v2.3 of the extension
Two new tokens have been introduced for mass mailing and they keep the URL in tact.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and posted here: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues/50

I have not had a chance to see why the tokens were not working for me, but I can add them manually:

```
https://example.org/wp-civicrm-basepage/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/gdpr/comms-prefs/update&reset=1&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
```

Replace example.org with your domain and wp-civicrm-basepage with your slug for the basepage you are using.

Update:   Version 2.2 of the extension has fixed the issue with tokens

Comment: Magic that worked!